# How to set custom HTTP headers to every request from a WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

As with API21+ this deprecated: @Override public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url)
how to properly add some custom headers to every request from the WebView to the backend servers?

(We need to add these headers to reach the test systems by iRule over the load balancers)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overloaded method `shouldInterceptRequest (WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)`

The `WebResourceRequest` object has a method `getUrl()`

Comment: OK, found that, but there's only a method request.getRequestHeaders() - nothing to modify or add request headers. How is that possible there?